# Re-opening files in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

For definitely not malicious reasons, I need to have a batch file always open.
I have some base code:

```
:b

echo off

tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" |find ":" > nul

if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "game.bat"&start game.bat

goto b
```

And it works fine if want notepad.exe or blah.txt and etc.
Except for batch files, as the program itself is a batch file,
the system sees cmd.exe is already open.

Comment: There should be a `timeout` command in the loop in order to avoid excessive processor load...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It works except for batch files, as the system sees cmd.exe is already open.

1. Give your batch file a `Title` by adding the following command to `game.bat`:

   ```
   title %~nx0
   ```
2. Check if `game.bat` is running by using `tasklist` with `/v` option:

   ```
   :b
   @echo off
   tasklist /v | find "game.bat" > nul
   rem errorlevel 1 means game.bat is not running, so start it
   if errorlevel 1 start game.bat
   rem timeout to avoid excessive processor load
   timeout 60
   goto b
   ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) - TaskList displays all running applications and services with their Process ID (PID) This can be run on either a local or a remote computer.
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.
- [title](http://ss64.com/nt/title.html) - Change the title displayed above the CMD window.

Comment: What's `find ":"` for?

Comment: @aschipfl I've no idea. It was in the OPs original file so I left it there.

Comment: @aschipfl Perhaps to match the `:` that `cmd` adds before the window title?. I changed the answer to a better solutions that avoids the problem.

Comment: Your [former approach](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38487031/1) using `/FI` and `WindowTitle` should have worked fine (perhaps even better as your [current one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38487031/2) matches `thegame.bat` also). I think I know the reason for `find ":"` now: in case no matching tasks are found, `tasklist` returns something like `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.`; `find ":"` recognises that output due to the colon after the word `INFO`; in case there are matching tasks running, `find ":"` finds no match and sets `ErrorLevel`...

Comment: @aschipfl That makes sense. However the window title on my machine at least (where I'm running as admin) get set to "Administrator:  game.bat" - which confuses things :/ The new approach also sets the `errorlevel` correctly. 1 => not running, 0 => running.

Comment: @aschipfl What I still don't understand is that the OP first kills "game.bat" (when the errorlevel = 1 ie not running) and then starts it. I don't think the kill is needed.

Comment: In the question, `ErrorLevel` is `1` when the task *is* running as *no* colon is found; but `taskkill` should fail anyway as the image name is not the batch file name but `cmd.exe`, so it seems indeed useless. Concerning the `Administrator:` output: this should *only* be present with the `/V` switch...

Comment: @aschipfl `Administrator:` is also required when matching windowtitle using `/fi` otherwise the match fails. And `/fi` doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: Agree about the timeout. Added to the answer.