# Open file sleep then close infinite loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file which opens 4 cmds and then goes to the corresponding
folder and executes some other bat files which then execute python scripts.
I basically want to have this batch file

```
:loop
start cmd.exe /k "cd C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder1 & call run.bat"
start cmd.exe /k "cd C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder2 & call run.bat"
start cmd.exe /k "cd C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder3 & call run.bat"
start cmd.exe /k "cd C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder4 & call run.bat"
goto loop
```

open these 4 cmds and then wait about 30 minutes and close and open them again, so it would look something like this

```
:loop
start cmd.exe /k "..."
sleep(1800000)
exit
goto loop
```

does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: There is the `timeout` command to do the sleep;

Comment: With "close" you mean killing the related task? if so you need a way to identify the correct process (by `tasklist` command), get its PID and use that for the `taskkill` command; one way is to specify a unique window title (by `title` command) and to search for that using `tasklist /V` and `find`/`findstr`...

Comment: @aschipfl I've got almost everything figured out but the problem is I can't use taskkill because the process PID will change every time I re-run the batch file

Comment: That's why I was talking about the window title; you will need to get the PID for each loop iteration...

Comment: See [Re-opening files in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38485921) for some hints

Comment: do you want to kill the still running `run.bat` or just the remaining black window that keeps open, when `run.bat` finishes? (hint: `cmd /?` see `/c` and `/k` switch)

Comment: @Stephan I just want to run run.bat and after let's say 30 minutes terminate it and run it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "RunBat" /d "C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder1" call run.bat
```

starts `run.bat` in a new window with the title `RunBat` with the working directory `C:\users\ivan\desktop\folder1` (no need for a `cd` command)

```
timeout /t 1800 >nul
```

pauses the execution for (30min*60sec) 1800 seconds. (`>nul`: don't show the timer)

finally

```
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq RunBat*"
```

kills all `cmd` windows where the windowtitle starts with `RunBat` (this way you don't need the PIDs). (Give all your "daughter processes" the same title, so you can kill all of them with a single `taskkill` command; or give them unique titles to be able to kill them separately)

Put a label and a `goto` around, and you're done.